# ANDROID: Activity state after pressing the back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Imagine you have the following sequence of activities:

```
Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C
```

When you are on Activity C, pressing the native back button, takes you to Activity B. Now what is the state of Activity C? Is it still in memory or it has been finished?

If it is still in the memory, is there a way to resume the activity? Other than starting another instance of this activity...

I should add that this is the standard case where you do not use any flags including: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: it's finished i.e. not in memory anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider reading [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

More specifically the part that answers your question:

> When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored).

Now for your second question… you can keep reading the same page…

> when you start an activity, you want to bring forward an existing instance of it (instead of creating a new instance on top of the back stack)

So if you read that… you will find…

> You can do these things and more, with attributes in the 
> manifest element and with flags in the intent that you pass to
> startActivity().
>
> In this regard, the principal  attributes you can use are:
>
> taskAffinity
> launchMode
> allowTaskReparenting
> clearTaskOnLaunch
> alwaysRetainTaskState
> finishOnTaskLaunch
>
> And the principal intent flags you can use are:
>
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: i have mainDashboard->profileview-profileupdate once am doing changes and updates goto profileview with updated details and then backstact need to maintain maindashboard and all.please help me

Answer (score 7):

Default behavior is that when you press hardware "back" button, current activity will be removed from the backstack and activity "destroy" sequence will be initiated. From that moment you should not rely on the fact that it might be somewhere around - it is all up to Android to decide when does it actually kill this activity.

What my previous investigations show is that victim's `onDestroy()` will be called only when new activity is done loading and is idle.

You can specify `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for your activity in Manifest. This will ensure that only one instance of activity is created at the time

Comment: i have activity a,and activity b,in activity b i have a form and radio group.if am doing radio group operations and fill the form and back press and once again cone to activity b how can i see those old form details and clicked radio button and all.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not in memory. It gets finished when you press the back button. You should use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the `androidmanifest.xml` for that particular activity for which you want no new instances to be created if an instance is already there. For further information [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) link will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In the following sequence...

```
Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C
```

When you will press back button in `Activity C` then `onBackPressed()` method will be called. The default behavior of `onBackPressed()` is to finish the current activity until you `Override` the functionality.

So, in normal case, after back press the current `Activity` will be destroyed and you can't find it in the `Activity Stack`, so you can't resume it.

You will find more information from Android Developer's doc in below link...

[Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)