# How to save activity state after pressing back button?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities A and B first one having products list and second one is the shopping cart. On click of a button in the list I am adding products to the cart.

Now I go to the cart and delete some items from it. I press back and came to the activity A again. Now if I go to the B(cart) again the list is null i.e there are no products in the cart.

I am using  `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save an restore the instance of cart activity but that is not working. Perhaps this is happening because I clicked the back button which destroyed cart activity and these methods were never called. I referred to this question: [Saving activity state on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android) and this [Activity state after pressing back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279416/android-activity-state-after-pressing-the-back-button). On pressing of back button activity is destroyed and popped out of the stack so I maybe its the case that I cannot use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

What I should use to save the products in my cart activity even if I press back button and how can I retrieve that on recreation of the activity? During some research I got to know I can use shared preferences, or SQLite database to store my activity state but I didn't found a good implementation. Any help regarding this is appreciated. Please share any useful SO links or tutorials regarding the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you save your Activity's state when exiting? Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308628/how-do-you-save-your-activitys-state-when-exiting-android)

Comment: what you have used to show list of product?? array list or products come from database

Comment: I am using ArrayList to show products, I have a ProductClass and Products are the objects of this class

Comment: @Mohit I have stated in the question that `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` are not working. The possible duplicate you have marked isn't addressing my problem. I have edited they question, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Trigger your saving function call inside destroy method of your activity.which will save the details before it get destroyed. The other thing is you can override `public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }` to move your task to back.